# How to provide whitespace between a displayed Icon and Data in a Datatables Ajax table column field

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables, whitespace

In one of my controllers, I have an Ajax Datatables process generating a table as my index function. In this process in one of my date columns, I have added logic that displays an icon beside the date if the date is today's date or past date, but if it is a future date then it just displays the date.

```
$table->editColumn('followup_date', function ($row) {
// check to see if record is todays date or older, if so display Bell icon next to date
  $date = Carbon::parse($row->followup_date);
  $today = Carbon::now();
  if ( $today > $date ) {
     return $row->followup_date ? (true ? ' <i class="fas fa-bell-exclamation red"></i>' : '') . $row->followup_date : '';
  } else {
     return $row->followup_date ? (false ? ' <i class="fas fa-bell-exclamation red"></i>' : '') . $row->followup_date : '';
  }
});
```

This works grand, however, the icon displays in the table column field right beside the date data without a space between. Such as 'IconDate' and I want it displayed as 'Icon Date'. How does one successfully inject a space between the icon and the date in this return statement?

My thought was something to do with '&nbsp' however I have not found a successful way to implement it in the code. I'm sure I am missing something simple but all my attempts at added the space between icon and date have failed.

In response to AndrewJames with regard to what I had tried. I had been thinking that I needed to insert the space between the two elements, icon and date. So I had explored different ways to try and use   in some manner to the lsft of ) and before  the $. Such as  `)&nbsp; . $row` OR `) . &nbsp;$row` OR `) . &nbsp; . $row` and a bunch of other options.

Comment: Can you show us your _unsuccessful_ attempt to use `&nbsp;`? What is the end-result HTML? And what does it look like on the page? Having said that, this feels like a CSS issue, more than anything else.

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks for your comment, it got me thinking down a different path that lead me to the answer. I had been thinking that the whitespace needed to go between the two elements but because of your comments, it got me thinking that maybe the answer lay with including the '&nbsp;` within the icon element. Once I started thinking down that path the answer came quite quickly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some of the questions Andrewjames asked me, it got me thinking that rather than add the whitespace between the two elements maybe the answer lay with attaching the whitespace to one of the elements. That seems to the thought I needed. The answer is to add the whitespace inside the ( ) attached to the  element:

`return $row->followup_date ? (true ? ' <i class="fas fa-bell-exclamation red"></i>&nbsp;' : '' ) . $row->followup_date : '';`

This provides the whitespace between the icon and the date when displayed in the table.